# Do plants grow back in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've been running around Amalur picking most of the glowing plants and trees that dot the landscape. Since my alchemy is so low, however, I'm doing a pretty awful job at actually receiving any items for my troubles.

Do plants respawn in KoA? How long does it take?

Comment: Within the confines of the demo, I couldn't tell you. I imagine it is probably a zone load thing.

Comment: My answer's been updated with some specific details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they do grow back.  I don't know specifically how long it takes, but here's an idea: I got a house (Gossamer End) in Canneroc, Webwood, and upgraded it to grow some plants in the basement.  I return to this house after each quest and by that time any plants that I had picked on my way out have often grown back. I can say that some plants (*seem to) take longer to grow than others, but for the most part, they don't take long.  Maybe a day or two in game.

Unrelated:  I just wanted to add this... Do the forests in this game conjure thoughts of James Cameron's Avatar?  They do for me.  Okay, time to stop talking and getting back to playing.

Comment: *(Added February 11th) You'll see your Scarwood Tree and Star Thistle regrow before your Black Cohosh, for some strange reason.

Comment: 2 game days for most plants.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a few things that do not cause plants to respawn:

- Saving and loading
- Fast travel between two locations (ie, changing zones)

There's a timer for it, to be sure.  I picked a Black Cohosh plant near the first town, and checked on it periodically as I ran other quests in the game.  I estimate it took between 3 and 4 hours of "real" time for the plant to regrow.

After I purchased and upgraded Gossamer End in Canneroc, I did some experiments by picking the plants in the basement and then sleeping for extended periods.  There are three types of plants that spawn in the basement of the home:

- Star Thistle, which respawns after approximately one day in game
- Scarwood Tree, which respawns after approximately two days in game
- Black Cohosh, which respawns after approximately three days in game

I'd say from this, you can't really expect to "farm" wild plants in an area without some manner of advancing the game time.  Any bed will do, but with the amount of time involved, you're probably better relying on new areas and the stocks of merchants to accumulate ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

Just save and exit the game, disconnect your system from the internet, and turn the system clock ahead.
Plants should respawn as soon as you log back into the game.